# Pointer as parameter

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

if you have a simple function e.g `int open(const char *path, int oflags);` you could pass a string directly as `*path` e.g `"filename.txt`. You also could pass a `&foo` (which is an address, it might have no sense in this case). You can even put a normal pointer in it.

So my question is, is actually an **address** expected when you have a pointer as parameter or is a just some data expected which fits to the parameter (in this case `const char`). I wondering because you can pass ascii directly without problems.

Thx.

Comment: You pass directly a string LITERAL. This means you are passing the address of that `const char` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expects a pointer.  A string constant, e.g. `"filename.txt"`, actually has a pointer value:  An array is created to hold the string, and the value of the expression is the address of that array, i.e. a pointer to it.

Comment: ah, so if you create "this is a strin", in system it will make an char array of it? Thanks

Comment: That's right.  You can think of it as an anonymous `char` array.  It will normally be allocated in read-only memory, so you can't modify its contents, but other than that it's like a `char []`.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that the type of string literals is `const char[]`, and it implicitly decays into a pointer when passed to `open`.

Comment: @szczurcio It would be even more correct to point out that the type of a string literal is `char[n]`, where n is the length of the string+1.

Comment: Yes, the length of the array is the length of the string plus one (for the terminating `\0` character).

Answer (score -1):

Your example case works because, in C, pointers to arrays point to the first element of the array. For example, in this code snippet

> int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
>
> int sum;
>
> int SumOfArrayElements(int *a)
>
> {
>
> /*
>
> code to calculate sum
>
> */
>
> }
>
> sum = SumOfArrayElements(arr);

`arr` is the pointer to the array and points to `arr[0]`.

Strings in C are character arrays (i.e., there is no difference between strings and char arrays). So when you pass `"filename.txt"`, the complier reads it as a character array pointer, which points to `"filename.txt"`.